# Что такое getKey в этом коде?

Tags: javascript

```
function getKey(k) {
  return `a key named ${k}`;
}

const obj = {
  id: 5,
  name: 'San Francisco',
  [getKey('enabled')]: true,
};
```

в консоли набираю

```
obj.id - получаю 5
obj.name - 'San Francisco'
obj.getKey('enabled') - 

Uncaught TypeError: obj.getKey is not a function 
<anonymous> debugger eval code:1
```

Что это такое и как это использовать?

Comment: Object.keys(obj) - посмотрите какой ключ возвращает функция

Comment: Array(3) [ "id", "name", "a key named enabled" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ES2015 появилась возможность **[Вычисляемых имён свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2)**. Это позволяет добавлять в скобки [] выражение, которое будет вычислено, как имя свойства

```
var i = 0;

var a = {
  ['foo' + ++i]: i,
  ['foo' + ++i]: i,
  ['foo' + ++i]: i
};

console.log(a.foo1); // 1
console.log(a.foo2); // 2
console.log(a.foo3); // 3
```

Как следствие у вас имя свойства будет: "a key named enabled". Обратиться к нему можно также через скобочную нотацию:

```
obj['a key named enabled']
```

```js
function getKey(k) {
  return `a key named ${k}`;
}

const obj = {
  id: 5,
  name: 'San Francisco',
  [getKey('enabled')]: true,
};

console.log(obj['a key named enabled']);
console.log(obj[getKey('enabled')]);
```